# How can I configure the Windows 7 Task Manager to always display processes from all users?

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

How can I configure the Windows 7 Task Manager to always display processes from all users?  I don't want ot always have to click on the button in the bottom left corner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

**[Create a Shortcut or Hotkey to Open Task Manager’s "All Users" View in Windows 7 or Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-a-shortcut-or-hotkey-to-open-task-managers-all-users-view-in-windows-vista/)**

*One of the reasons why I prefer to use the built-in administrator account, no button, but a checkbox. :)*

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) as your task manager. This one shows all the processes by default, as well as a lot of other information which the default one doesn't show.

Comment: not really answering the question, do you? :)

Comment: You are right. Just pointing out an alternative.

Comment: For process explorer to show you the user names you must run it As Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to click on the "Show processes from all users" button once.
Win7 will remember this setting for the next time.

If this isn't happening for you, then there's a problem.

Edit: This answer dates from 2009.
Nowadays UAC must be disabled with reboot.

Comment: no problem but the default behaviour.

Comment: @Molly: Are you saying this is the default action? Then why have I never encountered it?

Comment: @harrymc: That isn't the default behavior for me on any of my Windows 7 machines.

Comment: @harrymc: you have UAC turned off?

Comment: @Molly: I do. One more reason to hate UAC.

Comment: well, that explains that. when UAC is in 'full swing' it will always revert to the default setting and you will have to hit the button. so, knock off UAC or create a shortcut as explained in the tut i have posted. btw, most interesting link at the end of the article, if you want to "Create Administrator Mode Shortcuts Without UAC Prompts in Windows 7 or Vista" ... if you don't want to kill UAC altogether, that is.

Comment: @harrymc please edit the answer: to make this working you need to disable UAC, then reboot. Only after that the behavior you describe starts working. About the security — well, I'm using Windows as a VM *(for various testing purposes)*, and security is definitely the last things I care of *(I just don't give enough access to the VM to wreck on my system if something go wrong)*.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of UAC. Viewing all processes requires elevated permissions (since it allows you to affect user accounts other than your own). Since elevation can require credentials or prompting, it's unable to open automatically. It's a security feature, basically. You can run with UAC off, but that introduces other risks and may or may not be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this setup to have Task Manager always handy and showing all processes. The only external tool is **NirCmd** (free):

1. Configure Task Manager checking *Hide when minimized* menu option.
2. Create a new task in Task Scheduler, check *Run with highest privileges*, Trigger: At user logon, Delay task for: 10 seconds, Action: Start a program, *%ProgramFiles%\NirCmd\nircmd.exe*, Arguments: *exec min %SystemRoot%\system32*\taskmgr.exe

This will open Task Manager automatically and minimize it in notification area. When you open it, it will already show all processes. Don’t close it, just minimize it again. The 10 seconds delay is required (at least in my case) because otherwise Task Manager would be initially minimized in taskbar instead of in notification area.