# Is there a way to start Taskmanager in Windows 7 showing processes from all users?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure the Windows 7 Task Manager to always display processes from all users?](https://superuser.com/questions/81976/how-can-i-configure-the-windows-7-task-manager-to-always-display-processes-from-a)

Just a the title:

Is there a way to start Taskmanager in Windows 7 showing processes from all users from the beginning?

I never want to see anything else on my notebook.

Comment: @slhck You are right, but I scanned the first 2 pages of results for 'taskmanager all processes' here.

Comment: Hm, wasn't there a script popping up under your question's title telling you about exact duplicates? It's even the first "Related" question in the sidebar.

Comment: @slhck Nothing I noticed or had to click away

Comment: Hm, it should be something [like that](https://img.skitch.com/20110623-th38iu97ieuajmad4bpn6cqe25.jpg), but well, it's no big deal.

Comment: @slhck OK close it as Duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [elevated Task Manager](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/10499-task-manager-create-elevated-shortcut.html) shortcut to use instead for it to always open as "Show Processes From All Users".

Hope this helps,

> This will show you how to create a
>   elevated Task Manager shortcut that
>   will "run as an administrator" in
>   Windows 7 when opened. It will open as
>   if you clicked Show processes from all
>   users in the default Task Manager.

Comment: +1 Why didn't I ask earlier? So many lost cklicks.